# Multi-line push notification flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the flutter_local_notifications package for push notifications. But in a notification tray, I want to show the complete message, no matter how many lines it takes. This is the code I have written

```
void showNotification(message) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      Platform.isAndroid ? 'com.headstrt.app' : 'com.headstrt.app',
      'Flutter chat demo',
      'your channel description',
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.High,
      styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(''),
    );
```

I have specified a style also but still, all lines are not being displayed.

[image]

Comment: Tried giving the full text in `BigTextStyleInformation('')`?

Comment: It actually displays like that

Answer (score 7):

In BigTextStyleInformation, you must specify the message value passed to the showNotification function.

my own code as an example;

```
  Future<void> _demoNotification(Map<String, dynamic> icerik) async {

  String longdata = icerik["notification"]["body"];

  var bigTextStyleInformation = BigTextStyleInformation(longdata); //multi-line show style

 AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
 AndroidNotificationDetails(

        'push_messages: 0',
        'push_messages: push_messages',
        'push_messages: A new Flutter project',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        showWhen: false,
        enableVibration: true,
        styleInformation: bigTextStyleInformation);

NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    1,
    icerik["notification"]["title"],
    icerik["notification"]["body"],
    platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: icerik['data']['routing']);

    }
```

Comment: Note that the title of notifications is always single line and might also get truncated because of the icon or time information (e.g. `5min ago`). We found that limiting ourselves to 30 chars for the title almost always ensures to never be truncated (but the extrem is 11 chars depending on the language).

Comment: Thanks for BigTextStyleInformation(longdata) this Property @eyponder , but i am already using BigPictureStyleInformation() ..Is there any way to use both of this properties together? i am unable to assign both.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not really up to you. In Android, the default for a single notification is on line. If you want to see the entire message you need to drag the notification down.

Comment: It doesn't work. I can't drag the notification down.